# Dynamicdatadisplay charplotter set header in code

Tags: c#

http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/

How can i set Chartplotter axis header in code?

```
plotterTotal.HorizontalAxis = new HorizontalDateTimeAxis() { Name = "dateAxis" };
                        plotterTotal.VerticalAxis = new VerticalIntegerAxis() { Name =         "powerAxis" };
```

Analog for this xaml

```
 //<d3:Header  Content="Counter power"/>
                        //<d3:VerticalAxisTitle Content="Power" Name="valueAxis"/>
                        //<d3:HorizontalAxisTitle Content="Date"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post but what the hey...
https://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/discussions/219647

Basically if you have set the Chart Plotter in the xaml you set the header for the chart and give it a Name property.

Then in your code, reference the property and set its content.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For answering questions, it's best to include the information from the relevant link. In the event that it is removed from that site, your answer will still be full.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me.

```
HorizontalAxisTitle horizontalAxisTitle = new HorizontalAxisTitle();
horizontalAxisTitle.Content = "abc";

VerticalAxisTitle verticalAxisTitle = new VerticalAxisTitle();
verticalAxisTitle.Content = "def";

plotterTotal.Children.Add(horizontalAxisTitle );
plotterTotal.Children.Add(verticalAxisTitle  );
```